# Connecting via higher bandwidth WAN to Untangle VPN

Tags: load-balancing, openvpn, wide-area-network

I have 2 WANs on my gateway/firewall, set to load-balancing mode, in which one is a

20mbps (www.xxx.yyy.zzz) and the other
10mbps (aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd) line.

I have an Untangle server sitting behind the firewall accepting incoming connections. And I noticed that the all the client OpenVPN config are currently set to connect on aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd.

Question is, will changing the OpenVPN config to connect on www.xxx.yyy.zzz increase the connection bandwidth - or - will the load balancing rules on the gateway/firewall still apply?

I use speedtest.net to test internet speed (to see if ISP live up to their promise), what do you recommend for testing LAN or VPN speed?

EDIT: Seems like I cannot avoid stating that the link bandwidth are symmetric, up and down the same.

EDIT: I thought that since VPN has a persistent connection, then it will bind to which ever line it first connects to the server, therefore changing to www.xxx.yyy.zzz will increase the bandwidth / speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are always bound by what the NIC can handle to start with. However, this does not seem to be an issue here. Another limiting factor is your bandwidth: what does 10 && 20mbps represent? If your ISP provides the `www.xxx.yyy.zzz` with 20 down and 5 up and your other line `aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd` 10 up and 10 down, then the answer to your question is no, it won't matter about which line your VPN is connected to.

And you can always modify the rules on the gateway/firewall to unthrottle the  VPN connection too, but if the gateway is balancing the connections, you still should dedicate one WAN connection for VPN, just like you would SSH/HTTPS because of the broken session issues you would face.

Comment: Actually, I know about the dedicated connection etc which on my NETGEAR it's called protocol binding. That setting would more obviously boost my connection directly. So, I actually meant to ask the less obvious case, whereby the client chooses which line to connect in the first place, given the existing set-up.